# What is the meaning of C# with shortcut icon appears in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Working on some legacy codes - what is the c# class with black arrow overlay 
[image] icon in visual studio 2010 and why it appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have [a link to an existing item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx).

This technique is used when you want to share code.

When you edit the file with the described Icon, it also changes the source where it has been linked from.

**Edit:** To create a link to an existing item: (taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx))

1. In Solution Explorer, select the target project.
2. On the **Project** menu, select **Add Existing Item**.
3. In the **Add Existing Item** dialog box, locate and select the project item you want to link.
4. From the **Add** button drop-down list, select **Add As Link**.